# Acompanhar progresso por Requirement

Tags: team-foundation-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível exportar em Excel Os Requirements em uma coluna e as suas Respectivas Tasks em outra coluna mas de maneira em que eu possa visualizar e acompanhar a evolução dos requeriments, preciso ver quantas tasks um requirement tem neste mês em relação ao mês passado. Só consigo ver um abaixo do outro e isso impossibilita uma pivot table por exemplo visto que o requirement e a task estão em uma unica coluna.